# Finding Minimum of Error Function. Confused About Meaning of Critical Values.

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, error-function

I have the error function

$E(\mathbf{w}) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N \{ y(x_n, \mathbf{w}) - t_n \}^2$,

where

$y(x, \mathbf{w}) = w_0 + w_1x + w_2x^2 + \dots + w_Mx^M = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^M w_j x^j$

This is the sum of squares of the errors between the prediction $y(x_n, \mathbf{w})$ for each data point $x_n$ and the corresponding target values $t_n$.

By substitution, we have

$E(\mathbf{w}) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N \left( \sum\limits_{j = 0}^M w_jx^j_n - t_n \right)^2$

When finding the minimum of the error function, we set it equal to $0$:

$\dfrac{\partial{}}{\partial{}w_i} E(\mathbf{w}) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N x_n^i \left( \sum\limits_{j = 0}^M w_jx_n^j - t_n \right) = 0$

The error function is always positive. However, that does not necessarily mean that it is always increasing. This means that it could have many critical values, right? In which case, how do we know that we are solving for the global minimum and not a local minimum? My textbook says to minimise the error function, but that only makes sense if there's a global minimum, right?

So in reality when we set it equal to $0$, as was done above, what critical point are we actually solving for?

I've become very confused thinking about this, so I'd appreciate any help and explanations to clear this up.

Comment: Perhaps you show us the error function you wish to minimize, clearly identifying what the variables being optimized are, what the input data is, and what constraints (restrictions), if any, there are on the variables being optimized.  Then readers will have a more-informed basis on which to provide advice.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I apologise. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ordinary linear least squares problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Computation.

Because the optimization problem is convex (convex quadratic objective function with no constraints), every stationary point is a global minimum.

If the problem is non-degenerate (full rank), there will be a unique global minimizing solution, otherwise there could be an infinity of solutions, all obtaining the same global minimum objective value. There is widely available specialized software to robustly solve such problems.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/do-we-need-gradient-descent-to-find-the-coefficients-of-a-linear-regression-mode/164164#164164

Comment: Can you please explain this on a more elementary level? How can every critical point be a global minimum?

Comment: Because the function being optimized is convex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization . If you want to invest the effort and have the necessary math background, you can read (at least the first several pages of) "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe, freely available at author's website http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ .

Comment: So it only has a single critical value? In other words, once this function starts increasing, it continues to increase indefinitely?

Comment: Because if it didn't increase indefinitely after that, then it would end up having multiple critical values.

Comment: If it is a full rank (non-degenerate) problem yes. We can not determine whether the problem is non-degenerate unless you provide a concrete problem instance. Nevertheless, if you solve the problem by any of the (recommended) means listed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/do-we-need-gradient-descent-to-find-the-coefficients-of-a-linear-regression-mode/164164#164164 you will get a global minimum. But if the problem is degenerate, the solution will not be unique, even though all solutions achieve the same global minimum objective value.

Comment: If degenerate, there can be infinitely many critical values, but they all achieve the same objective. For instance, x + y = 1 and 2*x +2*y = 2.  There are infinitely many solutions achieving a perfect fit.